# Does edtftpnetpro.dll Version 9.1.2 support any of the following key exchange algorithms?

Tags: enterprisedt

The client has support for the following algorithms and I need to know if version 9.1.2 of edtftpnetPRO.dll on server side will support file transfer.

Please let me know if version 9.1.2 of /PRO supports any of the following:

ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported key exchange algorithm from this list for this version is diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256. You can determine this by running a program using the DLL with logging set to debug, connecting to a server, and then examining the debug log. All of the algorithms will be shown.